# Neovim + rainbow

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

Asking a question here worked before about this type of issue, so I will try again.

I'm trying to use the rainbow plugin (https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow) while learning clojure.

I *do* have `TERM=xterm-256color` set in my shell (zsh, if it matters).

I've also tried running nvim as `COLORTERM=xterm-256color TERM=xterm-256color nvim`

Here are my results:

vim:

[image: Vim results]

nvim:

[image: Neovim results]

If anyone has any advice or settings to try, I'd be extremely obliged. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your not the only one to notice https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues/31

It looks like something doesn't work properly to activate the plugin in neovim. Adding the following to your nvimrc

```
let g:rainbow_active = 1
autocmd VimEnter * RainbowToggle
```

makes the plugin work for me.

The autocmd just forces the plugin to start. If the plugin gets updated this might make it stop working since it could toggle it off.

---

Second answer

After more digging it appears you only need to put the following into your nvimrc.

```
syntax on
let g:rainbow_active = 1
```

The auto command gets fired on `syntax on` assuming `g:rainbow_active` is in your nvimrc.

Comment: Man, it's weird, in some envs in works, in others it just doesn't no matter what I do. Either way, thanks for the attention and the answer!

Comment: @Hoopes I'll ask some of the neovim devs to take a look. The plugin shouldn't break like this.

Comment: @Hoopes do you have `syntax on` in your nvimrc? The only things in my nvimrc as the two items listed above to get the plugin to load automatically.

Comment: Yeah - I must have some weird terminal setting difference. I swear I set up my two envs the exact same, but one works and the other doesn't.

I can do ```:RainbowToggleOn``` , but it just turns all of the parens a single color (and implies it wasn't already on?). Anyway, I'm glad there's already a github issue for it. I'll keep track of it as it goes.

Thanks again!